# Filter an array within a range when keys are timestamps

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an array with the keys as timestamps - the actual keys are unix time, I have just formatted it here for simplicity. How can I filter this array so that it unsets all values and only keep the array between **2013-08-02 00:00:00** and **2013-08-02 00:02:00** ?

```
2013-08-01 23:58:30 ---->> 322 active call(s).
2013-08-01 23:58:45 ---->> 322 active call(s).
2013-08-01 23:59:00 ---->> 324 active call(s).
2013-08-01 23:59:15 ---->> 324 active call(s).
2013-08-01 23:59:30 ---->> 327 active call(s).
2013-08-01 23:59:45 ---->> 330 active call(s).
2013-08-02 00:00:00 ---->> 336 active call(s).
2013-08-02 00:00:15 ---->> 343 active call(s).
2013-08-02 00:00:30 ---->> 342 active call(s).
2013-08-02 00:00:45 ---->> 342 active call(s).
2013-08-02 00:01:00 ---->> 335 active call(s).
2013-08-02 00:01:15 ---->> 325 active call(s).
2013-08-02 00:01:30 ---->> 324 active call(s).
2013-08-02 00:01:45 ---->> 322 active call(s).
2013-08-02 00:02:00 ---->> 322 active call(s).
2013-08-02 00:02:15 ---->> 319 active call(s).
2013-08-02 00:02:30 ---->> 317 active call(s).
2013-08-02 00:02:45 ---->> 313 active call(s).
```

Comment: What's the typical size of the array?

Comment: Will you always be filtering between two unix timestamps that definitely exist as keys in the array? Or are the start and end points possibly missing in the array (and you need to filter all points between them)?

Comment: A few thousand elements for the size. And I will always be filtering unix timestampsthat will definetely exist in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is small then use a naive implementation:

```
<?php 

foreach($inputArray as $key => $value) {

if($key < $lowerTimeBound || $key > $upperTimeBound) {
    unset($inputArray[$key]);
}

}
```

This is not efficient for a large number of entities.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly complex procedure. There is no native PHP function for filtering an array by the key name. `array_filter` only filters by the key value.

So you need something like this:

```
$calls = array(...); // your array

// get the times as the values of an array
$times = array_flip(array_keys($calls));

$boundaries = array(
    'start' => new DateTime('2013-08-02 00:00:00'),
    'end' => new DateTime('2013-08-02 00:02:00'),
);

// this function filters the times
// times outside the $boundaries will be removed from the array
$times = array_filter($times, function($val) use ($boundaries) {
    $time = new DateTime($val);

    if (($time < $boundaries['start']) || ($time > $boundaries['end'])) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});

// keep only the elements in $calls whose keys are in the $times array
$calls = array_intersect($calls, array_flip($times));
```